# How to select count(distinct) with additional where clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id, count(distinct clicks.transaction_id) as unique_clicks
FROM clicks
WHERE date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1;
```

This query counts the number of unique clicks by their transaction ID for an offer.

Now, I want to add the unique number of clicks for mobile and desktop users. Along the lines of:

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id, count(distinct clicks.transaction) as unique_clicks, 
     sum(case when clicks.mobile = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as mobile_unique_clicks, 
     sum(case when clicks.mobile = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as desktop_unique_clicks
FROM clicks
WHERE date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1;
```

The problem with this is that it won't count unique transaction IDs. Is there a way to do this with one query? And what kind of covering indexes would I need to keep this efficient?

Comment: Can you post some sample data? I don't think it's that complicated, but I don't know how your data looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id, count(distinct clicks.transaction_id) as unique_clicks, 
     count(DISTINCT case when clicks.mobile = 1 then clicks.transaction_id else null end) as mobile_unique_clicks, 
     count(DISTINCT case when clicks.mobile = 0 then clicks.transaction_id else null end) as desktop_unique_clicks
FROM clicks
WHERE date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1;
```

You can use COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure you understood the dilemma. It's the transaction id that should be distinct. I'm not really sure what your query is doing.

Comment: @AllTheCode Yes, sorry, I used another column in the CASE

Comment: @AllTheCode This query counts distinct transaction_ids, distinct transaction_ids where mobile=1 and distinct transaction_ids where mobile=0. If I you need something else then I really didn't understand your question.

Comment: Hmm you are right. I will do some testing to see what performs the best.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
SELECT clicks.offer_id,
       count(distinct clicks.transaction_id) as unique_clicks,
       sub.mobile_unique_clicks, 
       count(distinct clicks.transaction_id) - sub.mobile_unique_clicks as desktop_unique_clicks
FROM clicks
JOIN 
(
   SELECT clicks.offer_id, count(distinct clicks.transaction_id) as mobile_unique_clicks,
   FROM clicks
   WHERE date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1 AND  clicks.mobile = 1
) sub
WHERE date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can move your query to a `subquery` and use `distinct`:

```
select offer_id, 
       count(transaction) unique_clicks,
       count(case when mobile = 1 then 1 end) mobile_unique_clicks,
       count(case when mobile = 0 then 1 end) desktop_unique_clicks
from (
       select distinct offer_id, transaction, mobile
       from clicks
       where date > '2014-12-01 17:43:30' and offer_id = 1
) t
group by offer_id
```